# Idioms/Phrase for Obvious No

Tags: idiom-requests

There are idioms for an obvious yes when answering a question maybe if you were offered something and replying for example : 'Does the pope pray?' And various other ones.

What are the equivalents for a no?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/184306/13804.  Also, I was going to flag this as general-reference, but I've discovered it is surprisingly hard to search for idioms by meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

> ***Are there cold days in hell?***

(A variation on the [*it'll be a cold day in hell*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27ll+be+a+cold+day+in+hell) idiom)

Alternatively, how about:

> ***Does a snowball stand a chance in hell?***

(A variation on the [*snowball's chance in hell*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowball%27s_chance_in_hell) idiom)

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***When hell freezes over*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=When+hell+freezes+over%2Cwhen+hell+freezes+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhen%20hell%20freezes%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20hell%20freezes%20over%3B%2Cc0)

> until hell freezes over
>
> *Forever I will fight for these children until hell freezes over*. Usage notes: also used in the form *when hell freezes over* (never): *They said they would get back together when hell
> freezes over*. Etymology: based on the idea that hell (a very hot place
> where people are punished forever) can never freeze [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+hell+freezes+over)

***When Burnham Wood comes to Dunsinane*** --Shakespeare. [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/quand-les-poules-auront-des-dents.103788/)

> *Sure he'll help me wash the dishes...when Burnham Wood comes to Dunsinane.*

Comment: Although I would understand the second reference, I would find it a bit...recherche. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With obvious no's, I think the most important thing is tone of voice.  Barring that, you have:

There's a drawn out "sure", something like "suuuuuuuuuuuure".  Or "Do pigs fly?" Or:

"Sure just let me [insert something preposterous]"

For example:

"Do you have a knife?"

"Sure, let me just get it out of my magical purse..."

"Can you help us put out that burning building?"

"Sure, let me get that fire extinguisher i always carry around."

Comment: *When pigs fly* would actually be a good response, with a linked reference or two, since the question is asking for idioms, not simply responses or how to be sarcastic.