# Idioms or phrases to answer to obvious (yes) questions?

Tags: idioms

I've come across this analogous question for the opposite case [Idioms/Phrase for Obvious No](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292612/idioms-phrase-for-obvious-no) but couldn't find one for mine.

I'm looking for phrases like "Does the Pope pray?" or "Does a bear shit in the woods?".

Thank you.

Comment: "Is the Pope a Catholic?" is the more common version in my part of the (bear-free) woods.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few websites that list out some examples and a suggested term to search for on Google.

[Witty Ways to Say “Yes”](https://pairedlife.com/etiquette/Funny-and-Creative-Ways-to-Say-Yes)

- What’s the opposite of no?
- If I was a regular jerk, I’d say no to this one.
- Is the mitochondria the powerhouse of the cell?
- My two thumbs are standing in salute.
- Is the sun hot?
- My guts tell me that you are worth all the trouble.
- Do fishes swim?
- Something tells me I should trust you. But, I think it's just your words.
- Is one plus one equal to two?
- It appears that you have read my mind.
- Are boogers salty?
- Come on, humor me.
- Do pigeons fly?
- Tell me more.
- Is the pope catholic?
- Do vacuum cleaners suck?
- Is water wet?
- Is the hypotenuse the longest side of a triangle?
- Does a bear live in the woods?
- I’ll answer you with my favorite ‘Y’ word—Yes!
- Is the sky blue?
- I totally ‘scored’ getting asked by you. Yes!
- How do you spell yes?
- Would you take ‘yes’ for an answer?
- I haven’t said no yet, right?
- Would I be too tall for you if I were standing on cloud 9?
- Am I not holding my two thumbs up?
- There’s a 100% chance that I’m going say yes to that one.
- Like a dog wagging its tail in excitement!

[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6dklozy)

- does a bear shit in the woods?
- Is the pope (a) Catholic? phr.
- do beavers piss on flat rocks?
- does a bird have wings?
- do sheep wear sweaters?

A Google search of "sarcastic interrogative affirmatives and negatives" produces more...

[A lecture on the use](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25474889?seq=1) - Archer Taylor Memorial Lecture 2006: Is the Pope Still Catholic?: Historical Observations on Sarcastic Interrogatives

[Sarcastic Interrogative](https://katexic.com/word/sarcastic-interrogative/)

sarcastic interrogative. noun. Defined by folklorist Charles Clay Doyle as “stock questions with glaringly obvious yes or no answers. The function of each such question is to respond derisively to a prior query, itself calling for a yes or no answer so as to suggest that the answer to the original query is too obvious to be worth proffering seriously.” Perhaps the most famous example: “Is the Pope Catholic?” And perhaps the most canonical: “Can a duck swim?”

Some colorful examples:

- Is a frog’s arse watertight?
- Does Barbie have a plastic fanny?
- Is a pig’s butt pork?
- Does a snake have knees?

Comment: I'll just point out that in my experience, the positive sarcastic interrogative is used far more frequently than the negative, to the point where nearly any question phrased as "Is X a Y?/Does X Y?" can be interpreted to means "yes", even if you don't know anything about X or Y. The last example phrase, "Does a snake have knees?" is unusual in its negative interpretation, and would likely take an extra beat to parse in conversation, since it subverts the typical meaning of a phrase like that.

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, "obviously".

A computer salesman to an elderly gentleman who was asking a lot of "dumb" questions.

Salesman:  *Are you new to computers?*
Gentleman:  *Obviously.*

Answer (score 0):

"Does a duck with a boner drag weeds?"-bubbles

"Does the tin man have a sheet metal c**k"- also bubbles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).